# Category counts for query results

Tags: categories, search, relatedto, query

I'm trying to display results from a search. I want to display the categories represented by the search results and the entry count for that category. Think of how Amazon's "refine results" sidebar works, something like:

> **Results listing**
>   ...
>
> **Categories**
>   
> Planning and Funding (9)
>   Design (19)
>   etc.

I can easily get the count of *ALL ENTRIES* in each category with this:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('resourceCategories') %}
  {% set entryCount = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
  ... do something...
{% endfor %}
```

However, if I want to get counts for ONLY the returned search results. I've tried this:

```
{% set resourceEntries = craft.entries(queryParams).section('and, not organizations, not presentersAndAuthors') %}
{% for category in craft.categories.group('resourceCategories') %}
 {% set entryCount = resourceEntries.relatedTo(category).total() %}
  ... do something...
{% endfor %}
```

But I get the count for ALL entries (the same results as the top example).

Any idea as to what am I missing or not understanding?

Comment: Did you try to create a new query instead of executing the same object again and again? Also what are your `queryParams`

Comment: I did try creating a new query. Same results. The queryParam variable is built with some basic defaults (order, subLeft, subRight) and then a relatedTo call from merged with a category ids. like so:   {% set queryParams = queryParams|merge({
    relatedTo: categoriesArray   }) %}
Which means there is a relatedTo inside the queryParams and I'm wondering if that is the issue. Maybe my question should be, how to get a category count for a craft.entries object? I assume stepping through each entry and building an array is not the most efficient way?